# How can I push my array that contains a specific value to the last position?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my array, and I would like that `username` is always at the beginning and `password` is always at the end.

```
  array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "string"
    ["scale"]=>
    int(0)
    ["length"]=>
    int(191)
    ["unique"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["columnName"]=>
    string(5) "email"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(8) "isActive"
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "boolean"
    ["scale"]=>
    int(0)
    ["length"]=>
    NULL
    ["unique"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["columnName"]=>
    string(9) "is_active"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(8) "password"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "string"
    ["scale"]=>
    int(0)
    ["length"]=>
    int(64)
    ["unique"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["columnName"]=>
    string(8) "password"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(8) {
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(8) "username"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "string"
    ["scale"]=>
    int(0)
    ["length"]=>
    int(25)
    ["unique"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["columnName"]=>
    string(8) "username"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(9) {
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "integer"
    ["scale"]=>
    int(0)
    ["length"]=>
    NULL
    ["unique"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["id"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["columnName"]=>
    string(2) "id"
  }
}
```

I could get the array that contains the fieldname `password` to the end with this code:

```
$item = $myArray[2];
unset($myArray[2]);
array_push($myArray, $item);
```

But this is actually not what I am looking for. Because password is not always key 2

Comment: Add tag for the programming language you're using.

Comment: ah ok, it is php

Comment: Can you post the array as var_export or json_encode? That will be much easier to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) will do what you want. It uses a custom sort function that sorts `username` to the top and `password` to the bottom of the list. All other values will generally end up in the same order they started in, although that may be unpredictable.

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {  if ($a['fieldName'] == 'username' || $b['fieldName'] == 'password') return -1;
                                  elseif ($a['fieldName'] == 'password' || $b['fieldName'] == 'username') return 1;
                                  else return 0;
                                });
```

I made small [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iY91a) with only a couple of values from each entry; for that the output result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fieldName] => username
            [type] => string
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fieldName] => email
            [type] => string
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [fieldName] => isActive
            [type] => boolean
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [fieldName] => id
            [type] => integer
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [fieldName] => password
            [type] => string
        )    
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working! Can you explain a little bit, because I don't understand why it is actually working. Why is password one time   "$a" and ather time  "$b"

Comment: @Jarla When you are sorting using a custom function like this you don't know whether a value will appear in the `$a` or the `$b` variable, it just depends on the order in which the `sort` processes entries in the array. So you have to allow for `'password'` to be in `$a` or in `$b`. The result changes depending on which variable it is in (because the sort function returns -1 if `$a < $b` and 1 if `$a > $b`) so if it is in `$a` you want it to sort later than the other value the array (so return 1), while if it is in `$b` we want the other value to sort earlier so return -1. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this since I don't want to manually retype your array to real code.

The code uses array_column to make a flat array of fieldname and searches for "password".
If it's found it adds a copy of it last in the array and removes the original then does array_values to reindex the array.

```
$fieldname = array_column($arr, "fieldName");
$password = array_search("password", $fieldname);
$username = array_search("username", $fieldname);


if($password !== false){
    $arr[] = $arr[$password];
    unset($arr[$password]);
}
if($username!== false){
    array_unshift($arr, $arr[$username]);
    unset($arr[$username]);
}
$arr = array_values($arr);


var_export($arr);
```